# Sharepoint add content type to list after deployment

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, content-type

I'm creating a Sharepoint 2010 feature using Visual Studio.

In previous build of my feature I created `ServiceItem` list.

Now I need to add custom ribbon button to this list. As only one way to add this button to one list I found that I need to create custom ContentType (`ServiceItemCT`).

This work great on my development machine. But when I update feature on production server the content type is not connected to list instance.

I can just see `ServiceItemCT` in site gallery. Is there any way how to refresh whole list definition to use my content type?